# How to implement a condition within a Join clause in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I'm attempting to port a Postgres table definition query into Spark SQL for use in an AWS Glue script. The structure of part of my query is something like the below example, which runs in Postgres:

```
select newevents.name 
from cases c
join events newevents on c.id = newevents.case_id and not exists (select 1 from events events2 where events2.case_id = c.id and events2.id > newevents.id)
```

However, when I try the same query in pyspark with the call
`spark.sql(that_query)` I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 767, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "Table or view not found: `states`;
```

From trial and error it appears that the problem is caused by the "exists" condition in the join. Is this possible to do in the dialect of SQL used by Spark, or will I need to move the condition to the where clause or otherwise restructure my query?

Comment: did you add `dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("name_of_table")` before executing the queries?

Comment: @VectorXY Yes, for each of the tables used. The clause I gave above is part of a larger query that did run successfully as long as I removed that particular condition in the join (or moved it to WHERE)